# How do I reopen a question?

Tags: discussion

Lat week I [opened a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1011768/66509) and a very helpful Gentleman called Connor was busy giving me very good advice that I was following. Clearly to have been so helpful he must have been in possession of some insight into the purpose of the question. Now several other gentlemen have seen fit to close my question saying it was not clear enough for them (despite not making any effort to actually engage in offering help, which unless I am mistaken is what this forum is for?). Please correct both myself and Connor in this issue, or direct us to a forum that is actually conducive to asking questions and allowing them to be answered?

Comment: This is *not* a forum, please take the [tour] and read [ask] to familiarize yourself with our format. The question was closed for a very good and clear reason, just read the box and follow the links there to learn what's wrong with it and what you can do about that.

Comment: When a question is closed, no new answers can be added. Existing posts (questions and answers) can be edited and comments can be added. The closure isn't stopping Connor from further engaging. To have the question considered for reopening, you can try editing it to show exactly what specifically you want help with at this point. However, since your situation seems to require a back and forth to get through various unpredictable steps, I suggest seeking help on [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) which is suitable for getting that kind of assistance.

Answer (score 3):

I have some experience with old Dell XPS laptops, and they can be very idiosyncratic. It can be frustrating to troubleshhoot a Dell XPS laptop because the generic solutions provided in possible duplicate questions at Ask Ubuntu do not always work, and you need to dig deeper to find a solution that works on that specific laptop. If your question was reopened I would suggest trying some other things that Connor Payne didn't already suggest, although they might not work either. Allowing other users to post answers to your question would be a sufficient reason for reopening it in my opinion, so for starters I have voted to reopen your question.

As for the "closed as unclear what you are asking" message, if other users were allowed to post additional answers, maybe you would be asked to provide additional information, for example the output of a command in the terminal. If this terminal output was edited into your question, as is frequently the case, this would make it less unclear.